# С# - Повторение заданного условия

Tags: c#

Задание: Рассчитать значение функции в заданной точке. Использовать простейшие функции вида Y = 3 – X + 2 * X * X * X, не предусматривающие вычисления суммы ряда или использования рекуррентных формул.

Задание очень простое. Логику я реализовал.

Вопрос в другом: какими способами я могу сделать повтор условия в программе, так, чтобы перед вводом X и после вывода Y, программа запросила пользователя либо нажатие какого-либо числа(т.е X), либо нажатие какой-либо буквы(допустим 'q'), которая будет из себя представлять выход из программы. И чтобы подобный запрос появлялся, естественно, после каждого вывода "y" ровно до тех пор, пока не введу "q"

Я подумал сделать нечто подобное либо циклом while, либо рекурсией, либо и тем и другим.

Однако, ни к чему вразумительному так и не пришёл. Не особо понимаю, как это всё можно здесь реализовать.

Вот мой код.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, this program calculates the value of the function \"y = 3 – x + 2 * x * x * x\"!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please, choose any number or \"q\" to exit this programm.");
            string a = Console.ReadLine();

            if (a == "q")
            {
                return;  // здесь я решил сделать выход из программы через return, ибо другого способа не нагуглил
            }
            else
            {
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(a);
                int y = 3 - x + (2 * x * x * x);
                Console.WriteLine("The value of the function for x=" + x + " is " + y);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно, что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стыдно не знать про цикл с предусловием

```
var str = Console.ReadLine();
while (str != "q") 
{
   /*здесь парсите и проверяете ввод, делаете все что вам нужно*/ 
   str = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x;
        Console.WriteLine("Программа по формуле \"y = 3 – x + 2 * x * x * x\"!");

        do
        {

            Console.Write("Введите значения:");
            x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int y = 3 - x + (2 * x * x * x);
            Console.WriteLine("Значения x=" + x + " is " + y);
            Console.WriteLine("Повторить? y/n");
        }
        while(Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Посоветовал, что сам знал:) Если ваш вариант лучше, то я буду в будущем его использовать.

Comment: спасибо за совет:)

Answer (score -1):

Просто в бесконечный цикл завернуть?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true) {
    ...
    if (a == "q")
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем такую плохочитаемую конструкцию? Вы еще GoTo предложите.

Comment: Как по мне, читаемее, чем повторяющийся вызов `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Он и в вашем случае будет. Данные откуда-то надо брать новые.